# cross walk check android error

Tags: android, ant, crosswalk

I'm new one for for cross walk. I tried to setup for android in Ubuntu,I did the setup with [Here](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/system_setup.html). But i have the issue like bellow.please any one solve this problem?

`>$ crosswalk-app check android`
These are the output shown
  `+ Checking host setup for target android`
  `+ Checking for android... /home/user/android/Android/Sdk/tools/android`
  `+ Checking for ant... /usr/bin/ant`
 `+ Checking for java... /home/user/install/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java`
  `+ Checking for lzma... /usr/bin/lzma`
  `+ Checking for ANDROID_HOME... /home/user/android/Android/Sdk/`
  `+ Testing dummy project in /tmp/PZHyT7`
  `+ Creating com.example.foo [done]`
  `+ Building com.example.foo [aapt...] ** WARNING: BUILD FAILED`
`/home/user/android/Android/Sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:`
`/home/user/android/Android/Sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:694: Execute failed:`
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program`
`"/home/user/android/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt": error=13,`
 `Permission denied`
`..................`
`..................`
`... 46 more`
`Total time: 6 seconds`
`+ Building com.example.foo [done]`
`*** ERROR: Building project failed`
`*** ERROR: Consult logfile /tmp/PZHyT7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a permissions error. That means that your user account doesn't have access to something in your build path. i'd say start with:
`ls -la /home/user/android/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt`
and go up the path from there. 
you should eventually find that user/group permissions somewhere in there don't belong to you. once you find the culprit use `sudo chown myacct:mygrp offending_path`

however, you also got told that there is a log file at `/tmp/PZHyT7`, 
try `nano` /tmp/PZHyT7 and post the results.